# how to make python check dict duplicated keys instead of dropping silently

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

If someone write this code dict1 = {"a":1, "a":2}, python will drop the first one silently.
So we got dict1 = {"a": 2}.

How can I make python to raise an exception here instead of silently drop the first item?
This description is short but I think the question is clear enough.

Comment: Do you need this to happen with an actual dictionary literal? Or would some other way of constructing the dictionary suffice?

Comment: literal as there are some legacy code in this already

Comment: I don't think you can override the literal construction behavior... You can write your own subclass of `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, make it accept an iterable, and modify the behavior of repeated keys... but I don't see how you could construct it from `{a:1, a:2}` --> this will always create a standard dict, for which the last `key value pair` will overwrite a previous value with the same key!

Comment: When python evaluate `{"a":1, "a":2}`, it will always be `{"a":2}`.